# Why don't I get the correct error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my model

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

      validates_presence_of :title, :description, :image_url
      validates_numericality_of :price
      validate :price_must_be_at_least_a_cent
      validates_uniqueness_of :title
      validates_format_of :image_url,
                          :with => %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
                          :message => 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG ' +
                          'or PNG image.(gif|jpg|png)'

      protected
      def price_must_be_at_least_a_cent
      errors.add(:price, 'should be at least 0.01' ) if price.nil? ||
      price < 0.01
      end
    end
```

It validates all the errors correctly but i get the generic error messages. Here is the screenshot of the error messages[image: Rails Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have i18n gem installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the gem: I18n and see if the message appears fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in version of I18n gem. If you use Rails 3 or Rails 3.1 you should use latest stable gem. If you use Rails 2.3.x use older versions.
[I18n gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/i18n)

Comment: My I18n gem version is 0.5.0 and my rails version is 2.3.5. Should i use a older version of I18n?

Comment: I also supporting project on Rails -v 2.3.5 (I have I18n -v 0.4.0 installed). Try to install -v 0.4.0 and then uninstall -v 0.5.0